# Error when passing the scaled frame to the encoder `Encoder did not produce proper pts, making some up`

Tags: c, ffmpeg, video-processing, swscale

When I am passing the scaled frame to the encoder, I keep getting the error from the container `mp4` code. The sws context is defined as:

```
encoder->sws_ctx = sws_getContext(1920, 1080,
                            AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, 
                           scaled_frame->width, scaled_frame->height, scaled_frame->format, SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL, NULL );
```

The code for scaling the frame is as follows:

```
 sws_scale_frame(encoder->sws_ctx, scaled_frame, input_frame);
 if (encode_video(decoder, encoder, scaled_frame))
     return -1;
```

When I am passing the `input_frame` directly to the function `encode_video` I get no errors. So, I think the error is possibly from sws_scale_frame, maybe from the `context` or `frame` declarations. However, I am unable to figure out what?

The declaration of `scaled_frame` is as follows:

```
AVFrame *scaled_frame = av_frame_alloc();
scaled_frame->width = 854;
scaled_frame->height = 480;
scaled_frame->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
```

I have looked through the examples in the ffmpeg repo, but solution didn't work.

Comment: Please show the definition of AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P

Comment: Please look at this page for the definition: https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.4/pixfmt_8h.html

Comment: `PTS` is "presentation time stamp". This is how a _decoder_ knows when to display the frame. So, you may have to set the PTS for the [each] frame. Or, you have to set the video frame rate (e.g. 30 fps) so the PTS can be calculated. So, I'm not sure that a scaled frame (i.e. the pixel format, frame geometry, aspect ratio) matters as far as this goes. Audio frames also have a PTS. This is how A/V sync is maintained. Also, if a stream segment is corrupted, the PTS values can be used to resync. (e.g.) inject still frames, add/elide audio samples.

Comment: Also, there is `DTS` (decode time stamp). This tells [usually H/W decoders with limited frame buffer memory] when to decode the frame. This is so the decode process doesn't fall behind or run ahead too much. It doesn't wait too long to decode the frame and fall behind or run ahead and use too much memory.

Comment: Also, for a GOP (group-of-pictures), the incoming sequence to the encoder might be: `I-frame,B-frame,B-frame,P-frame`. This would be transmitted as: `I-frame,P-frame,B-frame,B-frame` so the timing would be (e.g.) `dts=0/pts=0 dts=1/pts=3 dts=2/pts=1 dts=3/pts=2` where each of these numbers is scaled by `n`

Comment: So, what is `scaled_frame->pts` for your frames? You may need to examine the PTS/DTS for the unscaled input and copy/adjust those values.

Comment: `scaled_frame->pts` is some garbage value.

Comment: ```scaled_frame->pts = input_frame->pts;
   scaled_frame->pkt_dts = input_frame->pkt_dts;``` seems to have solve the error.